# Extjs 4.1 - Show and hide some special Items in a form

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a windows with a items include 2 items like

```
var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'Hello',
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        layout: 'fit',
        items: {  
            xtype: 'form',
            border: false,
            hidden: true,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: '1'
            },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: '2'
            }]
        }
    }).show();
```

I make a button and i want show/hide first item (`fieldLabel : '1'`) in my window like

```
 Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'Show first item',
        visible: false,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        handler: function() {
            win.down('form').items.items[0].show(); // not working
        }
    });
```

But that's not working. How to fix that thanks

ps: I don't want to use id to get comp, b/c my form is dynamic thanks

 here is my full code **http://jsfiddle.net/aMKjN/**

Comment: But the form is hidden, so showing one of the children doesn't matter.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli if i comment `//hidden: true,` and the first i hide first item like `win.down('form').items.items[0].hide();` and i want to show all by `win.down('form').show();` and that's not working?

Comment: That's correct. If you show a parent, it doesn't mean the children are automatically shown, they retain their state.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli But how can i do that, my form has so many item and when i hide some items I can't show all item again (reset show)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It will show only the first `textfield`.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {

    text: 'Show first item',

    visible: false,

    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

    handler: function() {

        win.items.items[0].show();
        win.items.items[0].items.items[1].hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: But if i comment `//hidden: true`, and the first i hide first item like `win.down('form').items.items[0].hide();` and i want to show all by `win.down('form').show();` and that's not working?

Answer (score 0):

try this it will show only textfield 1

```
  Ext.onReady(function () {

   var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'Hello',
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        layout: 'fit',
        items: {  
            xtype: 'form',
            border: false,
//            hidden: true,
            items: [{

                xtype: 'textfield',
                id:'first',
                 hidden: true,
                fieldLabel: '1'
            },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: '2'
            }]
        }
    }).show();

    Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'Show first item',
        visible: false,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        handler: function() {            
          Ext.getCmp('first').setVisible(true)
        }
    });
});
```